# Check if the header has been assigned to the request in Go unit-testing

Tags: go, go-http, go-testing

I am trying to test the following line of code:

```
httpReq.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
```

I am mocking the request to an external api in this way:

```
httpmock.RegisterResponder(http.MethodPost, "do-not-exist.com",
        httpmock.NewStringResponder(http.StatusOK, `{
            "data":{"Random": "Stuff"}}`),
    )
```

And want to test if the request to the api has the header that I assigned. Is there a way I could achieve this?

Comment: can you not use your own `func` of `httpmock.Responder` type and check it inside that - instead of using `httpmock.NewStringResponder`

Comment: You are right. Thanks a lot for your comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of the comment by @Kelsnare I was able to solve this issue in the following way:

```
    httpmock.RegisterResponder(http.MethodPost, "do-not-exist.com",
            func(req *http.Request) (*http.Response, error) {
                require.Equal(t, req.Header.Get("Content-Type"), "application/json")
                resp, _ := httpmock.NewStringResponder(http.StatusOK, `{
            "data":{"Random": "Stuff"}}`)(req)
                return resp, nil},
        )
```

I wrote my own `func` of `http.Responder` type and used `httpmock.NewStringResponder` inside that `func`.

Answer (score 0):

[`response_test.go`](https://github.com/jarcoal/httpmock/blob/f754ca6a25820964d47324a6afd2939a0613576c/response_test.go#L225-L239) illustrates how the header is tested:

```golang
        response, err := NewJsonResponse(200, test.body)
        if err != nil {
            t.Errorf("#%d NewJsonResponse failed: %s", i, err)
            continue
        }

        if response.StatusCode != 200 {
            t.Errorf("#%d response status mismatch: %d ≠ 200", i, response.StatusCode)
            continue
        }

        if response.Header.Get("Content-Type") != "application/json" {
            t.Errorf("#%d response Content-Type mismatch: %s ≠ application/json",
                i, response.Header.Get("Content-Type"))
            continue
```

You can see an example of [table-driven test with `httpmock.RegisterResponder` here](https://github.com/jarcoal/httpmock/issues/95).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But isn't it checking the header of the response? I want to test if the request's header is set correctly

Comment: @Rustam Indeed, I was more on the response side with the mock library. Regarding the request side, do you mean like [this test](https://github.com/hashicorp/go-retryablehttp/blob/02c1586c8f14be23e7eeb522f1094afbabf45e93/client_test.go#L77-L81)?